# FMX SharedPreferences

Tags: android, delphi

In my android app, build with Delphi 10 Seattle I would like to access the SharedPreferences.
When running my app on an Android 4.3 phone the Sharing Preferences works well.
but when running this same app on a Android 5.1.1 phone my app will not start.
Does anybody have a clue to solve this?

Using the codesnipes below:

```
uses 
  AndroidApi.Jni.JavaTypes, AndroidApi.Jni.App, AndroidApi.Jni.GraphicsContentViewText, FMX.Helpers ;

{Public declarations }
  Prefs : JSharedPreferences;
  Editor: JSharedPreferences_Editor;
```

in FormCreate:

```
Prefs := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPreferences(TJActivity.JavaClass.MODE_PRIVATE);
Portfolio := Prefs.getInt(StringToJString('Portfolio'), 1);
EditSize.Text := IntToStr(Portfolio) ;
```

In FormClose:

```
Editor := Prefs.edit;
Editor.putInt(StringToJString('Portfolio'), StrToInt(EditSize.Text));
Editor.apply;
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: You got an exception ... use the debugger or add some logging to examine what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this won't even show in the debugger, so don't even bother trying.

Had this exact problem and it was driving me NUTS!!!!

Here's what I did to resolve. DO NOT declare the EDITOR.

This is my code to READ:

```
var
Prefs : JSharedPreferences;
  s: string;

begin
  prefs := SharedActivity.getSharedPreferences(StringToJString('NCVPPP'), 0);
  s := (JStringToString(prefs.getString(
    StringToJString('Key'), StringToJString('0'))));
  Registered := false;
```

This is my code to WRITE:

```
var
Prefs : JSharedPreferences;
//PrefsEditor: JSharedPreferences_Editor;
  s: string;

begin
  prefs := SharedActivity.getSharedPreferences(StringToJString('NCVPPP'), 0);
  //PrefsEditor := prefs.edit;
  Prefs.edit.putString(StringToJString('Key'), StringToJString(DeviceSerialNo));
  Prefs.Edit.commit;
```

Comment: Hi John-David Biggers

thank you very much for your solution.
I couldn't solve the SharedPreferences problem and finally I used the JVE.cofiguration component which solved my problem. 
I will rewrite my code and use your solution.
thanks a lot & best regards 
Frits

Answer (score 0):

The answer is wrong. 
What raises the exception is "TJActivity.JavaClass.MODE_PRIVATE"
If you want it to work you MUST use Editor, so to fix it just write

```
Prefs := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPreferences(0);
```

instead of

`Prefs := TAndroidHelper.Activity.getPreferences(TJActivity.JavaClass.MODE_PRIVATE);`

and that's it.